# How to update a RoR model's associations without updating the corresponding model's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have the following models (with corresponding database tables) in my Rails 3 application:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :service_users
  has_many :services, :through => :service_users

  attr_accessor :password

  attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation, :service_ids

  validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :confirmation => true,
                       :length => { :within => 6..40 }
  ...
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :service_users
  has_many :users, :through => :service_users
  ...
end


class ServiceUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :user
end

#User Controller:

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

I want to be able to update a User model's associated services without having to specify the password and password confirmation attributes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options...

If you have simple logic, like only validating the password when a user is created, this will work:

```
validates :password, :presence => true,
                     :confirmation => true,
                     :length => { :within => 6..40 },
                     :if => :new_record?
```

More likely, you'll want a combination so that users can update their password:

```
validates :password, :presence => true,
                     :confirmation => true,
                     :length => { :within => 6..40 },
                     :if => :is_password_validation_needed?

# Protect the password attribute from writing an
# empty or nil value
def password=(pass)
  return if !pass.present?
  @password = pass
end

private 

  def is_password_validation_needed?
    # Return true if the record is unsaved or there
    # is a non-nil value in self.password
    new_record? || password
  end
```

Comment: this is on the way but just be advised that if you use this in situations where you actually want to allow your user to change their password, if nil somehow creeps into that equation then no validation will be fired to prevent nil from being saved along with the model.  how this would happen who knows but i think setting an attr_accessor as outlined in the railscasts is a safer bet

Comment: Well, now my password is set blank. Maybe it is because I am calling update_attributes with params[:user] so it is overriding the password attribute with a blank password field since it's not set. How would I call update_attribute(s) with only the attributes I want to update? `def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end`

Comment: I would recommend a password setter function. I'll update the answer with my suggestion. You don't have a 'password' column in the database, right (that would be bad)? The Authlogic gem is a good place to get some insight: https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/password.rb#L235

Comment: Thanks a lot tihm! I changed my User model's encrypt_password function to include your line "return if !password.present?" and it works: `def encrypt_password
      return if !password.present?
      self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password);
    end`

Answer (score 2):

This could help:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations

Answer (score 0):

you will want to look into conditional validation to specify whether or not the password attribute in your model should be validated when you are updating/saving the model.  here is a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations) episode that, while a little dated, is still fairly straightforward and should get you off on the right path